# Question with images on products

Tags: magento-1.7, products

being a complete newbie with Magento, kinda' suffering a little bit but right now the question is this, if you check the following:

http://www.spartvs.com/ibiza-153.html

There's a lot of images coming on that product, the idea is to have 3 or 4, maybe 5 images max and then when people clicks on a color, then only the images associated with that color will appear, the way the images are set up within the product is as follows, please check attachment

[image: Screenshot of Images on Products]

The thing is, what I'm doing wrong? or maybe this what I am asking is not possible on Magento?

Thanks!

Comment: Arturo, you could review your question title: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question

Comment: You want what is called "color swatches"

Comment: FlorinelCHis thanks fo rthe suggestion, done, benmarks, thank you! where can I check more about this color swatches thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arturo, Ben's correct, you need to look at colour swatches. Before that however, you should familiarise yourself with configurable products.

This type of product allows you to create one parent product that in a simple form, links to a child product based on a selection of attributes, normally using a dropdown for each attribute.

Colour swatch extension hide the dropdowns and replace them with small swatches to indicate the selection.

A quick Google of "magento color swatches" will give you a few results. Personally, I've used the version available from Amasty, but others are available.